# Saving image to node.js server without express.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, upload, save

So I have been wondering how to save an image to node.js server without the use of express.(just learning node and want to make everything myself to learn node better, without express).

So far I have a form with the image as only input which I send with a post request. This is what I have so far on my server, which does not log anything.

```
if(req.method === 'POST') {

    if (req.url === '/upload') {

        req.on('error', function(e) {
          console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
        });

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg; charset=utf8'});

        req.on('data', function (chunk) {

            fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/uploads/dada.jpg", chunk, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("The file was saved!");
                }
            }); 
        });
    }
}
```

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**EDIT:** I fixed most of the problems, but the file is only saved as an image, but cannot be viewed like one. (Something is wrong with the content-type I guess, but don't know how to fix it)
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/M7w6y/) is fiddle of my whole app. I know I need to separate it in different modules, but I will do that later

Comment: Are you trying to upload?  In that case, not sure why you're listening on the `res` response object.  You should be listening on `req.on('data')` and saving that eventual payload out.  I'd probably also just respond with a 200, no need to include a content type.  You're not returning an image back from the server.

Comment: I must have hit my head pretty bad... thanks for the help man, I'll fix my mistakes and see what will happen

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/5FAUk/) is my code now. It does save the image and all, but the image cannot be viewed. I must be doing something wrong. Am I missing some content-type or something?

Comment: You need to append each chunk to your output file (looks like you're overwriting each chunk with the next).  Also, easier if you just update the code by editing your question.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that. I am a total beginner...

Comment: You'd want a combination of `fs.open` (prior to the data event) with `fs.write` (during the write events) and then `fs.close` in the `req.on('end')` event.

Comment: Any documentation I find is either for express.js or not very helpful. 
I am really not lazy, just can't really figure it out. Can you show me some code, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely forgot about this old question but now that I see it has quite some views, here is the solution I found:

```
var port = 1357;

var http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    mime = require('mime'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    GUID = require('GUID'),
    formidable = require('formidable'),
    util = require('util');

var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    if (req.method === 'POST') {

        if (req.url === '/upload') {

            req.on('error', function (e) {
                console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
            });

            var fileDirectory = __dirname + '/db/',
                form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

            form.keepExtensions = true;
            form.uploadDir =fileDirectory;

            form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {

                if (err) throw (err);

                var pic = JSON.stringify(util.inspect(files)),
                    upIndx = pic.indexOf('db'),
                    path = pic.slice(upIndx + 6, upIndx + 42);

                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                });
                fs.readFile('views/index.html', function (err, page) {
                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                    });
                    res.write(page);
                    res.write('<div>Download Link: </div><div>' + fileDirectory + path + '</div>');
                    res.end();
                });
            });

        }
    } else {

        //not important for question, handle other request
    }

});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server running on port: ' + port)
```